# how to get EmbeddedFiles from FileAttachment Annotation in pdf file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf

I am working on PDF annotation app i added PDF file annotation in iPhone it working fine it annotation also visible any reader but facing one issue How to get EmbeddedFiles from  File Attachment  Annotation in  PDF file whose is created annotation from desktop how can do for this issue

i am using this code for get contents and location of annotation  from  File Attachment  Annotation it working fine

```
 CGPDFDictionaryRef pageDictionary = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(pPage);
      //  NSLog(@"%@",(NSDictionary*)pageDictionary);
        CGPDFArrayRef outputArray;
        if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(pageDictionary, "Annots", &outputArray)) {
            [pdfAnnots release];
            return nil;
        }
     CGPDFArrayRef rectArray;
                if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(annotDict, "Rect", &rectArray)) {
                    break;
                }

                int arrayCount = CGPDFArrayGetCount( rectArray );
                CGPDFReal coords[4];
                for( int k = 0; k < arrayCount; ++k ) {
                    CGPDFObjectRef rectObj;
                    if(!CGPDFArrayGetObject(rectArray, k, &rectObj)) {
                        break;
                    }

                    CGPDFReal coord;
                    if(!CGPDFObjectGetValue(rectObj, kCGPDFObjectTypeReal, &coord)) {
                        break;
                    }

                    coords[k] = coord;
                }               

                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2],coords[3]);

                NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));

 CGPDFDictionaryRef aDict;

    if(CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(annotDict, "AP", &aDict)) 
    {

      CGPDFStreamRef textStringRef33;
        if(CGPDFDictionaryGetStream(aDict, "N", &textStringRef33)) {



            CGPDFDataFormat *format = NULL;

            CFDataRef contdata = CGPDFStreamCopyData( textStringRef33, format );

            NSData *data=(NSData*)contdata;
   }
```

please help me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

PDF embeds is not the same as annotations. Embedded files stored in `document` section instead of `page` section.

Annonation can contains embedded file, but mechanism of it's extraction is different.

First, you should see internal structure of annotation object. You can use function like this:

```
static void op_Applier(const char *key, CGPDFObjectRef value, void *info) {
    if (*(int *)info > 6) {
        return;
    }
    const char *valuestr = NULL;
    CGPDFObjectType type = CGPDFObjectGetType(value);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < *(int *)info; i++) {
        printf("\t");
    }
    printf("%s", key);
    switch (type) {
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeBoolean: {
            bool b;
            CGPDFObjectGetValue(value, type, &b);
            printf(" (boolean) : %s\n", (b)?"true":"false");
        }
            break;
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger: {
            int64_t i;
            CGPDFObjectGetValue(value, type, &i);
            printf(" (integer) : %lld\n", i);
        }
            break;
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeReal: {
            CGPDFReal f;
            CGPDFObjectGetValue(value, type, &f);
            printf(" (real) : %f\n", f);
        }
            break;
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeName:{
            CGPDFObjectGetValue(value, type, (void *)&valuestr);
            printf(" (name) : %s\n", valuestr);
        }
            break;
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeString: {
            CGPDFStringRef str;
            CGPDFObjectGetValue(value, type, &str);
            printf(" (string) : %s\n", CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(str));
        }
            break;
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeArray: {
            printf(" (array)\n");
            CGPDFArrayRef arr;
            CGPDFObjectGetValue(value, type, &arr);

            int t = *(int *)info + 1;
            int j;
            size_t size = CGPDFArrayGetCount(arr);
            for (j = 0; j < size; j ++) {
                CGPDFObjectRef obj;
                CGPDFArrayGetObject(arr, j, &obj);
                char buf[4] = {0};
                sprintf(buf, "%d", j);
                op_Applier(buf, obj, &t);
            }
        }
            break;
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary: {
            printf(" (dictionary)\n");
            CGPDFDictionaryRef dict;
            CGPDFObjectGetValue(value, type, &dict);
            int t = *(int *)info + 1;
            CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(dict, &op_Applier, &t);
        }
            break;
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeStream:
            printf(" (stream)\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf(" (NULL)\n");
            break;
    }
}

int t = 0; op_Applier("MyDictionary", yourAnnotationDictionary, &t);
```

Second, you should find path to your file (it will be `stream` object), and move to this object. This can be done with [CGPDFDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/Reference/reference.html) methods.

Third, get `NSData` from stream, and save it

```
CGPDFDataFormat format;
CFDataRef data = CGPDFStreamCopyData(stream, &format);

[((__bridge NSData *)data) writeToURL:resultUrl atomically:NO];

CFRelease(data);
```

P.S. PostScript syntax of PDF annotation can be different. Different libraries use different syntax, and you should implement all possibilities to make app, that works on *almost all* PDF files. Sample can be found in [this file in vfr Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader/blob/master/Sources/ReaderContentPage.m)